# Best way to leave PHP loop while waiting for user input and then return

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am making a quiz and have a PHP array of questions and answers.
My PHP script randomizes these and then runs through them in a loop until all questions in the array are done.

My problem now is that after the first question, when I switch to JQuery and request user input (clicking a button), the PHP doesn't wait and dumps the whole array of questions on the screen.

Is there some way to break out of a PHP loop to wait for user input and then resume where it left off?
I don't want to break out of the loop permanently, as I need to do this for each iteration of the loop, evaluate their answers and give them points etc.

Any helpful suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: not sure you understand the clientside\server side dynamic. php finish its job before anything goes to the browser. if you want to interact from browser to php you make a new background call usually via ajax

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is missing a basic understanding of PHP and javascript and the client/server - model. This knowledge is required first.

Comment: Can you include the relevant source code to your question please?

Comment: Rather than close the question, leaving me and future readers in the dark, can you enlighten us more on how this functionality is usually achieved?  Is AJAX the only option?

Comment: Are there any good tutorials on how to create PHP driven websites with interactivity?  Essentially the interface between PHP and Javascript...

Comment: You can use rest API for this purpose brother. As we know http Request response cycle and as we send request php is server side scripting language so it is processed on server and generates a response for us.

Comment: No, Ajax isn't the only option but for someone to offer a solid solution it all depends on the structure of your existing source code and how you have the questions stored. Me personally I would have the questions saved on a database and each piece of data saved would have [A Unique ID] [The Question] [The Answer] and I would use `php` to create a object with the ID/questions for javascript to use. Render the question to the page and use the unique ID for the input. this way no matter the order of asking you can use the ID to relate the answer to the database.

Comment: Off the top of my head, that would be my approach. You could also use javascript to show one question at a time and use the object to hold the clients answer. Once complete send the object back to `php` for checking :)

Comment: I decided not to use a database, because the questions and answers are only 1 word (the same word) as it's teaching language.  That's why I have stored the questions in a simple array in PHP.   Setting up and accessing a database to retrieve a single word is too much work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX